# What's best way to generate JSON from huge list of data?

Tags: json

I'm looking a fast solution to generate json from huge list, I'm currently typing JSON structure from list of data which contain state, counties and regions, each state may contain more than 80 words, it gives me a lot of tedious to do it with my hands. It takes a lot of hours.

This is basic structure of city name:

```
    {
    "state": "Alaska",
    "name": "Snowcity"
    }
```

Is there a way to compute it like load alaska_cities.txt and do index of loop each newline?

EDIT: Format of list looks like:

```
San Francisco
Los Angeles
St. Louis
Greenville
Memphis
Greenbay
Tampa Bay
Rosamond
Las Vegas
Firestone
...
```

Comment: What's a list, in this context? Are you referring to a particular type of data structure (and if so, what programming language are you working in)? Or is this data coming from a file? If so, what's the format of the file? Or is this list perhaps not even on a computer at all yet?

Comment: @user2357112 edited question, need to convert from list.txt to json while mantaining parent of state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your talking Javascript simply load the file using ajax, split by new line and iterate over the names:

```
var list = [];


    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", "/alaska_cities.txt", false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
            {
                var names = rawFile.responseText.split("\n")

                 names.forEach(function(name) {
                    list.push({state: "Alaska", name:name})
                })

                console.log(list)
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
```

Comment: But how do you return this in console? it wont save .txt

Comment: Save the json to a file?

Comment: It would do output in console, it's better.

Comment: I added a print to the console